# Excel - Add trailing zero's

Tags: excel, formula, trailing

In excel I have all sort of values in a column,

```
1      100
12     120
123    123
03     030
133    133
```

and I want to add zero's at the end till it reaches 3 digits.

Cheers

Comment: Cool. Configure it as decimal with trailing zeros :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
=A1&REPT("0",3-LEN(A1))
```

The Rept() repeats a character a certain number of times.  The 3-LEN(A1) figures out how many times to repeat.

[image]

Comment: Another popular one is `=left(a1&"000", 3)`.

Comment: @Jeeped never thought of that one, Cool.